# What is this called in HTML and where can I find some information about it?

Tags: html, css

[What is the name of this selector?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAkQ7.jpg)

Any help with the name of this selector and where I can find some information about it is greatly appreciated. Apologies in advance if I'm violating some form of format, new here.

Many thanks!

Comment: You posted a screenshot saying "Year 2021".. that is not a selector.. please clarify your question and add code snippets instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Apologies @PeterKrebs if I wasn't clear, the screenshot also shows chevrons along the left and right of the year (2021). Perhaps selector is the wrong term to use?

Comment: Well that is just a design element. You can right-click it and inspect and the browser development tools will show you what element it is. It is probably just a styled div or span..

Comment: @PeterKrebs Unfortunately I only have an image, is there anything similar that you have come across before?

Comment: `<input type="date">` maybe?

Comment: This depends on what the functionality is. It has similarities with an [expansion item from Quasar](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/expansion-item) it may also be just a link. You have no other information other than this small screenshot?

Comment: It's meant to work as a filter of sorts, clicking on the left and right arrows changes the year and the content below it respectively. So @John, that's not it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you actually need to build what you're looking for.

Here I made this for you.

```css
input[type="number"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.number-input {
  border: none;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.number-input,
.number-input * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number-input button {
  outline:none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.number-input button:after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
  font-weight: 900;
  content: '\f077';
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(270deg);;
}
.number-input button.plus:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.number-input input[type=number] {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  height: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#yearsp {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.contain {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div class="contain">


<span id="yearsp">Year</span>

<div class="number-input">
  <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" class="minus"></button>
  <input class="quantity" min="0" name="quantity" value="2021" type="number">
  <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus"></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this was what I was looking for, many thanks! Would like to upvote but I don't have enough rep for it sorry!

Answer (score 0):

That right arrow is a probably a icon, generated by a icon toolkit, like `fontAwesome`. You need to copy the code for linking it from a CDN service like [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome). Then you can copy the HTML from their [website](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/chevron-right?style=solid). They can be styled using regular CSS.

```css
.menu-section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: grey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-top: 1px solid #b0b0b040;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b0b0b040;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu-section span:first-child{
  color: #1a4d7d;
}


i {
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="menu-section">
  <span>Year</span>
  <span>2021</span>
  <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
</div>
```

You can search their site and use other icons as well.

Comment: Hi sorry was more of looking for something similar to the entire menu itself rather than the icons. Sorry for being unclear on that.

Comment: @zynqn See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks but the other answer was more of what i was looking for, still thanks for your help!